# Read file info of a zip-file in r

Tags: r

I want to read the time (timestamp) of zip-files in a particular folder. I have tried this:

```
file.info("C:/Users/foo/")$mt
```

This seems to read all the time stamps of the other non-zipt files in the folder.

I also used

```
file.info(list.files("C:/Users/foo ", pattern=".zip"))
```

This resulted in NA’s for all variables: size, isdir, mtime etc. are all < NA>

`list.files("C:/Users/foo ", pattern=".zip"))` shows the zip-files, as expected.

Q: How to read the creation date and time of zip files (in a folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm first disregarding one and maybe two typos: `Find.file` does not exist, and though possible, I don't often see a space at the end of a path.

Let me show you where your logic is missing something:

```
list.files("c:/Users/foo", pattern=".zip")
# [1] "file1.zip" "file2.zip"
```

Okay, so far so good.

```
file.info(list.files("c:/Users/foo", pattern=".zip"))
#           size isdir mode mtime ctime atime  exe
# file1.zip   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
# file2.zip   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

Okay, that's the problem. Why? Let's break it down by looking at one specific file. The first return from the working `list.files` is file1, let's try that:

```
file.info("file1.zip")
#           size isdir mode mtime ctime atime  exe
# file1.zip   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

Still a problem. Let's see where we are ...

```
getwd()
# [1] "c:/Users/foo/somewhere/else"
```

`file.info` has no idea what `path=` argument you provided to `list.files`: it assumes you are giving is absolute or relative paths to filenames. And you are: a path relative to the current directory. If you `full.names=TRUE` to provide the full path to all listed files, you'll see:

```
list.files("c:/Users/foo", pattern=".zip", full.names=TRUE)
# [1] "c:/Users/foo/file1.zip" "c:/Users/foo/file2.zip"
```

this is better prepared for other functions. From here, `file.info(...)` should work fine.

```
file.info(list.files(path="c:/Users/foo", pattern=".zip", full.names=TRUE))
#                        size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
# c:/Users/foo/file1.zip    0 FALSE  666 2018-04-30 07:31:24 2018-04-30 07:31:24 2018-04-30 07:31:24  no
# c:/Users/foo/file2.zip    0 FALSE  666 2018-04-30 07:31:26 2018-04-30 07:31:26 2018-04-30 07:31:26  no
```

Comment: I figured it out , I will accept your answer, it is more than complete.  I have corrected the typo, F by f. Thak you.

Comment: I was fairly verbose on this answer to help (you and/or others) with figuring out how to troubleshoot problems like this, akin to ["*teaching how to fish*"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). It could easily have been a comment with "add this to your call". Glad it helped.

Comment: nicely spotted. I was lucky to find this thread

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
file.info(list.files("C:/Users/foo ", pattern=".zip", full.names=TRUE)) $mt
```

adding `full.names=TRUE` to `list.files ()` seems to be the solution.